# how to override onpaint event C# from a HWND

Tags: c#

Here is my problem.
I have a handle (HWND) from a window, but I don't know the type of this window (It is not common window, I think is OpenGL or something like this), and I want to paint a gradient, it works code like below:

`//ptr is the HWND
Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(ptr);
newGraphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush, Height, 0, Height, coordStep);`

it draws the rectangle, but when the window moves, or updates, then disappear, so I'm looking a way to call the redraw when this window call the OnPaint. I need to do that from C#, but if I could find a way to do it using Windows API from C# will be very useful to me.
Thks in advance.

Comment: Is the window in or out side of your application (different process?)

Comment: I'm doing a plugin for Autodesk Inventor, so the window is from autodesk.